# Deserialize JSON into a sublevel object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Suppose I have this JSON:

```
{
    "Success": true,
    "Records": [
        {
          "f_EMail": "test@me.com",
          "f_FirstName": "firstname",
          "f_LastName": "lastname",
          "f_Country": null
        },
        {
          "f_EMail": "test2@me.com",
          "f_FirstName": "firstname2",
          "f_LastName": "lastname2",
          "f_Country": null
        }
    ]
}
```

My class looks like this:

```
public class Result
{   
    public bool Success { get; set; } 

    public IEnumrable<Dictionary<string, string>> Records { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works as expected. But I would like to write my class a little bit differently and put the values inside `Record.Data` as shown below.  I need to find a way to read and write to this model because some values are well known and I would like to access them more directly.

```
public class Result
{    
    public bool Success { get; set; } 

    public IEnumerable<Record> Records { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }

    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return Data[KnownRecordField.Email];
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return Data[KnownRecordField.FirstName];
        }
    } 

    ...
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think you can deserialize it directly to the new object in a different format. You will have to create a map after the deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to declare your dictionary as `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of `Dictionary<string, string>` you can take advantage of Json.Net's "[Extension Data](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/05/08/json-net-5-0-release-5-defaultsettings-and-extension-data)" feature to handle this.

- Mark the dictionary with an `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute.
- Make properties for all of the well-known values and give them `[JsonProperty]` attributes corresponding to their JSON property names.

The well-known JSON properties will be deserialized into their respective members on the class, while all of the remaining values will go into the dictionary.

```
public class Record
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("f_EMail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("f_FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hGZ1V7

---

If you want *all* the values to go into the dictionary (not just the unknown ones), you can still use the `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute, then use separate properties to read and write the well-known values directly from the dictionary.  Be sure to mark the properties with `[JsonIgnore]` to avoid potential conflicts during serialization.

```
public class Record
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Email
    {
        get { return GetDataValue(KnownRecordField.Email); }
        set { Data[KnownRecordField.Email] = value; }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return GetDataValue(KnownRecordField.FirstName); }
        set { Data[KnownRecordField.FirstName] = value; }
    }

    // use this method to avoid an exception if the well-known value
    // isn't present in the dictionary
    private string GetDataValue(string key)
    {
        object value;
        return Data.TryGetValue(key, out value) && value != null ? value.ToString() : null;
    }
}

public static class KnownRecordField
{
    public static readonly string Email = "f_EMail";
    public static readonly string FirstName = "f_FirstName";
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/I04oMM

Comment: It work great but i cannot use the JsonProperty on the properties because when I set the FirstName, it must add it to the Dictionnary. So i just used the JsonExtensionData on the Data object.

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure whether you wanted all the values to go into the dictionary or just the unknown ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `JsonProperty` attribute in record class.

```
public class Record
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "f_EMail")]
    public string Email
    {
        get;set;
    }    

    ...
}
```

Comment: It work only if i know the field name but i also need to insert all the ones that i don't know inside the Dictionary.